# design your custom menu

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page

I want to have my own menu. Just created basic Ul and li element to define menu like

```
 <ul >
     <li style="line-height: 16px;">Home</li>
     <li style="line-height: 16px; ">Documents</li>
     <li style="line-height: 16px; ">MySite</li>

  </ul>
```

I know somewhere in master page this is code which is used to define menu

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
                    id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
                    runat="server"
                    EnableViewState="false"
                    DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
                    UseSimpleRendering="true"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    StaticDisplayLevels="1"
                    DynamicHorizontalOffset="0"
                    AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
                    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
                    StaticPopoutImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/menudark.gif?rev=23"
                    StaticPopoutImageTextFormatString=""
                    SkipLinkText=""
                    StaticSubMenuIndent="0"
/>
```

How can i put my own menu instead of predefined sharepoint menu?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the **left bar** (so *quick launch*) you have to remove this element from the maste page:

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar"
```

Then add your **custom menu** and use *JS/CSS* to set the right position.

Comment: but if i remove that part of code and add my css then will i be able to part of menu as we do in navigation menu in site settings?

Comment: Also are you sure its DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar and not DeltaHorizontalQuickLaunch

Comment: no, of course you wont be able to mange your custome menu from site settings